# How can I prevent a C++ lambda from being inlined?

Tags: c++, lambda, inlining

I'm profiling some code that involves lambdas, and the inlining of the lambdas is making it difficult for me to understand what's going on. I'd like to prevent some of the lambdas from being inlined, whether through some function that takes a lambda and returns a non-inlinable version of it, or something I can add to a lambda declaration, or whatever. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check your compiler's documentation for options that disable all optimizations, such as inlining?

Comment: If you're profiling code, generally you want to get performance measurements representative of the best performance possible (i.e.  the compiler optimising to its heart's content) to correctly produce required results from inputs.  Turning off inlining (of lambdas or anything else is contrary to that.    Generally speaking, you may find that compiling without optimisation (which is the default for most compilers, unless you enable optimisation) may turn off inlining of lambdas.  But profiling without optimisation is viewed as pointless.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to bypass compiler optimizations (they are so good at seeing "through" things).  Maybe you can try to move the body of the lambda to a free function for now and call that from your lambda. And then add something like __noinline to that function. Or tell your compiler not to inline short functions (for gcc is see -fno-inline-small-functions)

Comment: Inlining decisions are completely up to the compiler. It isn't standardized at all. You'll need to tell which compiler you are using. Then maybe there is a ways to achieve it with compiler-specific attributes and such.

Comment: Disabling inlining when profiling is like asking Usain Bolt to *walk*, so you can get a more precise timing. But, in practice, nobody cares about the precise time for 100m walking. You just get the answer to "How fast is it when it is not fast".

Comment: The point here is that I pick _which_ functions don't get inlined, so that I can still inline most and get a good enough idea of the performance